# C# получение items из json

Tags: c#, json

Попытался написать код получающий items из json

```
response: {
count: 684,
items: [2, 5, 6, 7, 12, 20, 21, 22, 23, 34, 37, 42, 45, 46, 54, 57, 59, 61, 133, 169, 173, 175, 180, 182, 187, 190, 193, 194, 198, 199, 201, 230, 231, 234, 237, 254, 277, 287, 288, 316, 326, 334, 341, 345, 358, 366, 369, 373, 467, 469, 517, 701, 702, 713, 799, 907, 980, 1037, 1057, 1228, 1439, 1634, 2491, 2745]
}
```

Вот попытка, но она не работает

```
        JObject o = JObject.Parse(ТУТ json);
        string index = (string)o["response"]["items"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Пользуйтесь отладчиком, его для этого и придумали. То, что вы пытаетесь привести к строке, является переменной типа **JArray**:

[image]

Следовательно, код должен быть примерно таков:

```
string jsonStr = @"{response: {
                                    count: 684,
                                    items: [2, 5, 6, 7, 12, 20, 21, 22, 23, 34, 37, 42, 45, 46, 54, 57, 59, 61, 133, 169, 173, 175, 180, 182, 187, 190, 193, 194, 198, 199, 201, 230, 231, 234, 237, 254, 277, 287, 288, 316, 326, 334, 341, 345, 358, 366, 369, 373, 467, 469, 517, 701, 702, 713, 799, 907, 980, 1037, 1057, 1228, 1439, 1634, 2491, 2745]
                                    }}";
var json = JObject.Parse(jsonStr);
var items = json["response"]["items"] as JArray;

foreach (var i in items)
    Console.WriteLine(i);
```

Comment: http://i57.fastpic.ru/big/2014/0104/59/ea24335dce31c13722f2e3e39e0c4159.png

Comment: @Vlmake покажите код, а не картинки. Картинки довольно неудобно отлаживать

Comment: HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("https://api.vk.com/method/friends.get?user_id=" + Data.IDvk);
            HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            StreamReader myStreamReader = new StreamReader(myHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.GetEncoding(1251));
            string userslist = @myStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
            var json = JObject.Parse(userslist);
            var items = json["response"]["items"] as JArray;
            foreach (var i in items)
            MessageBox.Show(i);

Comment: а что такое **test.JArray** и **test.JObject**? Это какие-то ваши классы или что? Если говорить про JSON.NET, то там нет **test.JArray**, а есть **Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray** и **Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject**

Comment: Я не знаю я код в интернете нашел

Comment: ну так посмотрите, что вам мешает?